# Deleting The Last Character in A String Livecode Language

Tags: livecode

I need to delete last character in a string Livecode.

I have wrote this below in English.

```
on mouseUp    

   replace last character with Backspace in field"dialed"

end mouseUp
```

I am a newbie, so please use simple answers :)  Thank you.

Comment: Hi Tim and thank you I have tried the above code:  I have looked in dictionary in livecode, but it is no help, I also googled, cant find code for a simple delete char button. sigh.  I am super new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the last character of a field is very simple:

```
on mouseUp
  delete the last char of fld "Dialed"
end mouseUp
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, and doesn't even need code to handle if the string is empty!!  Wow thank you!

Comment: If the answer is useful, please click on the Accept icon on the left. That keeps people answering your questions.

Comment: Ok I might be dense, but there isn't a "Accept" button for me to click.  I do appreciate the answer it works flawlessly.

Comment: Okay, that's weird but if there isn't one so be it.

Answer (score 1):

If you think that is nice, what about:

```
delete character 2 of word 3 of line 4 of fld "dialed"
```

Comment: Jamal is soooo right! Also, this is not a solution to the given problem.