# How to clear a window at runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just learning Python.  I have a program that will choose a random image each time you click the mouse!!  How do I clear the window so images don't stack.  I am sure I am asking this question wrong because google is no help :(

Thank you and here is the code:

```
from graphics import*
import random
import os

win = GraphWin("My Window", 500, 500)

for x in range(5):

    cards = ["1.gif","2.gif","3.gif"]
    rand_card = random.choice(cards)
    img = Image(Point(250, 250), rand_card)

    win.setBackground('Black')
    img.draw(win)

    win.getMouse()
```

Comment: What tool are you using in python?

Comment: The IDLE and importing graphics.py.  I tried to use TKinter but I am on windows and it just won't work for me.

Comment: What version of the `graphics` module are you using?

Comment: Since a `GraphWin` is a subclass of `tkinter,Canvas`, you should be able to call `win.delete("all")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code at http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py, the `Image` class has an `undraw` function.  You can simply add `image.undraw()` with a check to make sure it's not `None` (as it would be for the first time in the loop:

```
img = None
win = GraphWin("My Window", 500, 500)

for x in range(5):

    cards = ["1.gif","2.gif","3.gif"]
    rand_card = random.choice(cards)
    if img:
        img.undraw()
    img = Image(Point(250, 250), rand_card)

    win.setBackground('Black')
    img.draw(win)

    win.getMouse()
```

(Note, change added based on cdlane's comment - initialize `img` to None so we don't get variable undefined.)

Comment: Scott, it worked!!!   Thank you so very much!!   Thank you to everyone who took time out of their day to answer.   I am so happy

Comment: Happy to help.  Like Mark said the [last time you asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33816216/1404311), feel free to upvote and/or accept any answers that you find useful.

Comment: I guess I need to turn "15" to upvote or like lol.  At the rate I ask questions It will be 2021 :)

Comment: You can always upvite (or downvote) on answers to your own questions. And you actually earn points for accepting an answer (by clicking on the checkmark).

Comment: When I run this example, I get "NameError: name 'img' is not defined".  Also, why is `win.setBackground('Black')` still inside the loop instead of simply before the loop as it's only needed once as the card undraws itself.  Ditto with respect to why is `cards = ["1.gif","2.gif","3.gif"]` inside the loop?

Comment: @cdlane You bring up good points - both of those could be removed from the loop.  I tend to just copy what the OP gives and give them a minimal change needed to do what they ask.  Regarding `img` undefined, that would be part of the minimal change I need to include, so I'll edit the fix for that in.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for the confusion.  The "img" variable is local to my computer.  This is a stub of a card matching game that I am trying to make.  "img1", "img2" and "img3" are pictures of different cute animals in the same folder as the program :)